# Using a mask div for a text

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm making a button using html5 and css3. I'm trying to make a hover animation like [this](http://piclair.com/71fue) for my button.

When mouse hovers over the button, a white circle expands from the center with the button text inside the circle in black font color (to make it more readable). I was trying to put a div inside the button, but I can't get the black text in the same position as the button text.

Comment: i don't think it is possible without any javascript.

Comment: maybe it's possible using css-animations.

Comment: actually i'm not quite interested in animations, because i can use them good enough both in css3 and jquery. My problem is the white circle with the black text, i don't know how to align it perfectly with the button one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed able to do without javascript without animations, just transitions

I was able to do this using an inner element and a pseudo-element on the inner element. Interesting concept but not very easy to change, a lot of hard coded values based on the element's height. Using a preprocessor like SCSS would make it a lot easier to manipulate

Anyway, here's the code (likely could be cleaned up a bit)

```
/* HTML */
<div class='outer'>
    Contacts
    <div class='innerCircle'></div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.outer {
    width:150px; height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:blue;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    line-height:50px;
    position:relative;
}
.innerCircle {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; left:50%;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
    transition:all .5s;
    height:0; width:0;
    padding-left:-10px;
}
.innerCircle:before {
    content:'Contacts';
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-2px;
    transition:all .5s;
    transform:translateX(-25px);
    top:-25px;
}
.outer:hover .innerCircle {    
    margin-left:-25px;
    top:0;
    height:50px; width:50px;
}
.outer:hover .innerCircle:before {
    top:0px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/S9eyL/)

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted to do, and i must thank you so much! Anyway there's a little problem, since this is going to be a menu for a sort of CMS, the section are dynamic and they change, so properties must changed as well automatically.. i tried changing the word in your example using a bigger one but the text in the circle disaligns

Comment: @Sevenarth Unfortunately you will have to change the `margin-left` value of `.innerCircle:before` for each otherwise unless you use javascript

Comment: i see. then thank you so much again! I'll try to find a workaround. :D